# Problem with Queue browsing when upgrading from 5.15.14 to 5.16.2

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, distributed-transactions

Has anyone also noticed an issue with queue browsing with 5.16.2?
It happens when using an XA connection and starting a session without a transaction context.
This always worked fine but no longer does. Instead one can see a exception, but only when debug logging is turned on:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Session's XAResource has not been enlisted in a distributed transaction.
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXASession.doStartTransaction(ActiveMQXASession.java:101) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed a few years back in 5.16.0 via [AMQ-2659](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2659). You need to set `xaAckMode=1` on your URL now, e.g.:

```
tcp://localhost:61616?jms.xaAckMode=1
```